# use openid connect without redirecting to security token service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, identityserver3

I have several ASP.NET MVC sites that will use [Identity Server 3](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3) as a shared Security Token Service.

These sites need their own local login page. Today they use WS-Trust to authenticate with Identity Server 2, but we want to upgrade them to use OpenID Connect on Identity Server 3.

We couldn't find any situation where OpenID connect supported active authentication like this, so we pursued the OAuth2 Resource Owner flow instead.

My first attempt at solving this is as follows:

**Startup.cs**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    TicketDataFormat = new AuthTicketDataFormat(),
    AuthenticationType = Auth.ssoAuthenticationType,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
    CookieName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsoCookieName"],
    CookiePath = "/",
    CookieDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SsoCookieDomain"],
});
```

**AccountController.Login** (post) has:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    ssoBaseUrl + "/connect/token",
    ssoClientId,
    ssoClientSecret);

var token = client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(userName, password, ssoScope).Result;

var client = new HttpClient();
client.SetBearerToken(token.AccessToken);

var token = client.GetStringAsync(ssoBaseUrl + "/connect/userinfo").Result;

var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(new JwtHeader(), JwtPayload.Deserialize(token));

var claims = jwt.Claims;

var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Auth.ssoAuthenticationType, "email", "roles");
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
```

**This works but...** we thought that there should be an owin component that simplifies the process. For example, we can see the following extension methods but none of them seemed to replace what we have above:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(
    new IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions {})

app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions{})

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions{})

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions{})
```

These extension methods, despite our best efforts to get them to work for our situation, never appeared to replace the need for our working code above, where we manually reach out to the token and userinfo endpoints and the cookie authentication in startup.

Are we missing something or is our solution the best one for this situation...active authentication using our own login page but using the latest security technology to accomplish it (OpenID connnect / OAuth2)?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in the same situation.  If not, at least thanks for the working code above.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sign in with no re-direction you will have to use Resource Owner Password Grant flow. See an [article](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/01/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-resource-owner-password-flow/) by one of the Identity Server authors. It's for ID server 2, but it should still be useful. There is also some info from the [documentation](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/overview/simplestOAuth.html) which is an example of how to (in ID server talk they call it resource owner password credential grant).

That being said, this flow is only in the framework because it kinda forced in by some of the contributors to the OAuth 2.0 spec, really it kinda goes against the idea of OpenID/OAuth. Having your site redirect off to login.yoursite.com might seem like a hassle, but really it's what you should be doing. In terms of User Experience I had a chat to a UX guy at my work (as I had the concern of UX) and he said that it's a common enough experience now (at least in enterprise) and it doesn't subtract from the users experience as all the magic happens un-seen to them under the covers of redirects.

I would STRONGLY recommend the Implicit flow with redirects. It's plain and simple juts how you should be doing it.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply and the link / advice. We do understand the concerns regarding the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Grant flow. In our case, these are trusted web applications that we own in-house and have full control over, so they line up well with the parameters of the resource owner flow. Also, the login pages for all of the sites have content requirements that can't be accomplished with a shared login page. The question we have is less about whether we should use this flow. Instead, we were hoping to discover a simpler way to implement it using prebuilt owin extensions.

Comment: I am also curious about getting the token and userinfo without redirect as i control both the client app and the Auth server.
Almost all the examples use redirect with the use case that the client app is a third party to the Auth server.

In my case the app is a SPA and we used this flow sending the user/pass over https to our Auth server